# JAVASCRIPT JSON.parse() return Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a response from a service, using https

```
rest.on("data", data => {
  response = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

I need parse this response but... I know the final result should be(I get this with postman)...

```
{ "code": 200,
"msg": "",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "t4ba",
        "devData": {
            "id": "bb2as",
            "state": "OK"
        },
        "entries": {
            "2019-05-26T19:03:13.9260000": 15,
            "2019-05-26T19:03:29.1690000": 26,
            "2019-05-26T19:04:16.6880000": 65
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "t4ba-2",
        "devData": {
            "id": "bb2as",
            "state": "Underperformance"
        },
        "entries": {
            "2019-05-26T19:03:13.9260000": 25,
            "2019-05-26T19:03:29.1690000": 45,
            "2019-05-26T19:04:16.6880000": 32
        }
    }
],
"dateResponse": "2021-03-26T19:04:16.6880000" }
```

When I run **JSON.parse(data)**

I get this errror

> "errorType": "SyntaxError",
> "errorMessage": "Unexpected end of JSON input",
> "trace": [
> "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input",
> "    at JSON.parse ()",
> "    at IncomingMessage. (/var/task/index.js:47:23)",
> "    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)",
> "    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)",
> "    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (internal/streams/readable.js:519:10)",
> "    at flow (internal/streams/readable.js:992:34)",
> "    at resume_ (internal/streams/readable.js:973:3)",
> "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)"
> ]

I think the "data array" field is the problem and I don't know how to solve it.

When I receive a response with empty data:[], everything works fine.

Comment: Why to parse, when it is already an object.

Comment: the JSON you've posted is valid - can you confirm that `response` is the string you've posted

Comment: @DeC - what makes you believe it is already an object

Comment: @JaromandaX https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/jOyqxPQ?editors=0011

Comment: The data itself looks fine. What are you using to make this request? Based on the error stack, seems like possibly a vanilla node request or the request is being streamed in. If so, you would need to wait for the `end` event to parse the data. Something like: vanillajstoolkit.com/polyfills/stringreplaceall/

Comment: "Unexpected end of input" is due to invalid json where not all the quotes or braces are closed properly. What you posted is valid but there is likely something else in that response

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to explain myself better.

Comment: `rest.on("data"` may not have ALL the data in one go - in this case, it's clear it does not - you may need to use `.on("data"` plus `.on("end"` (I think, or `'done"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm... The answer is easy...

Lets Start:::::

First, looks like you get a lot of data from your service...

On response.on("data"

Data is not complete at first, so, .on("data" "repeat himself" from init to end, then ur data is complete...

code

```
res.on("data", data => {
  someVariable += data;
});
```

then... in your .on("end"

```
rest.on("end", () => {
  MyJSON = JSON.parse(someVariable);
});
```

That's all folks.

Comment: THANKS! I spend a lot of time with that, Im really glad, THANKS!

Comment: Try look alternative for pure node request, outside are a lot of methods with better results. Remember close ur answer